# Is it correct to say "he is one of the most respected among all Romans"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Should it be "Most respected" or "most respected people/ones"?

Comment: You may use adjectival constructions without the nouns they modify. For example, the end of the first verse of the U.S. national anthem includes "the land of the free and the home of the brave." It's unnecessary and even wrong to insist on "the land of the free people and the home of the brave people."

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to use an adjective as a noun, when the context is clear. There is an example in a comment "The land of the free". Also in the Bible "The meek will inherit the Earth." English doesn't have suffixes to mark a word as an adjective or noun, so simply putting a word into a noun position makes it a noun.

However, you can write the phrase

> he is one of the most respected Romans

This means the same, is simpler, shorter and clearer.

Comment: Yes. Indeed, it is crystal clear to me even to non native like me.